Laid off on H1-B, can I still apply for Schengen visa in US to spend a week in EU and return to India?
I got laid off on H1B in the US. I am planning to travel to Germany to visit my childhood friends who are working there. I am wondering if I could apply for Schengen visa in the USA and visit EU for a week and return to India where I eventually get married in December.

You could apply, but they're going to ask about your employment and being unemployed and unmarried living in a country you're almost out of status in I'd say your chances are slim.
